# convert data table to list<>

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

i am trying to convert data table to list in web service to get it in java script . i tried the below code

```
rows = (from p in dt.AsEnumerable()
            select new TableProperty() { }).ToList<TableProperty>();

    for (int i = 0; i < rows.Count; i++)
    {
       // Get List of table Properties..
        List<TableProperty> tProperties = new List<TableProperty>();

        for (int j = 0; j < dt.Columns.Count; j++)
        {
            try
            {
                TableProperty propertyValue = new TableProperty()
                {
                    name = dt.Columns[j].ToString(),
                    serial = dt.Columns[j].ToString(),
                    address = dt.Columns[j].ToString(),
                    mobile = dt.Columns[j].ToString(),
                    password = dt.Columns[j].ToString()
                };
                tProperties.Add(propertyValue);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ex.ToString();
            }
        }


    }

    return rows;
```

where is dt is my data table ,TableProperty is the class which i set and get my properties

when i get it in java script , my value returns null

```
function draw_Result(ddata) {
        alert(ddata.length);
        for (var i = 0; i < ddata.length; i++) {
            alert("for");
            try
            {
                var post = ddata[i].name.toString();
                alert(post);
            }
            catch (e)
            {
                alert(e.message);
            }

        }
    }
```

any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
rows = (from p in dt.AsEnumerable()
        select new TableProperty() { }).ToList<TableProperty>();
```

Have you tried debugging the program to see what `rows` is after you assign it like that?

Also, you seem to first be assigning the `rows`, then looping over that collection only to create a completely new collection `tProperties` (which would probably contain what you'd expect) and at the end you return `rows` again. What is the purpose of `tProperties`?

It looks as if `rows` was a list of `TableProperty` objects which are empty - since for each row (`from p in dt.AsEnumerable()`) you select an empty object (`select new TableProperty() { }`) and at the end convert the enumerable to a list of still empty objects.

You'd need to do your mapping either at the point when you create the `TableProperty` - but that would imply that you know how many columns there are:

```
rows = (from p in dt.AsEnumerable()
            select new TableProperty() {
              name = p[0].ToString(),
                    serial = p[1].ToString(),
                    address = p[2].ToString(),
                    mobile = p[3].ToString(),
                    password = p[4].ToString()
 }).ToList<TableProperty>();
```

If you don't know how many columns to expect, you can always go with just the plain Enumerable - i.e. do the `for` loops using 
`var rows = dt.AsEnumerable()`

Answer (score 0):

Just a tip: You could always make an extension to the DataTable object. When you so-call extend the DataTable object, you make it possible to do this:

```
List<TableProperties> ListOfTableProperties = YourDataTable.DataTableToList<TableProperties>();
```

Here is how to do it:

Say you have this data model (a class):

```
public class TableProperties
    {
        public int Indexer { get; set; }
        public string DisplayName { get; set; }
        public string TypeName { get; set; }
    }
```

.. and you have this data table to work with:

```
DataTable tbl = new DataTable("test");
tbl.Columns.Add("Indexer");
tbl.Columns.Add("DisplayName");
tbl.Columns.Add("TypeName");
tbl.Rows.Add(2, "teststring1", "teststring2");
```

.. and when you do this:

```
List<TableProperties> urk = tbl.DataTableToList<TableProperties>();
```

... you get a list of type TableProperties.

The extension you need for this can be put in a static class of its own somewhere in your project. Here is the code for making such a class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Web;

    public static class ExtensionMethods
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Converts a DataTable to a strongly typed list
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T">Generic object</typeparam>
        /// <param name="table">DataTable</param>
        /// <returns>List with generic objects</returns>
        public static List<T> DataTableToList<T>(this DataTable table) where T : class, new()
        {
            try
            {
                List<T> list = new List<T>();
                foreach (var row in table.AsEnumerable())
                {
                    T obj = new T();

                    foreach (var prop in obj.GetType().GetProperties())
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            PropertyInfo propertyInfo = obj.GetType().GetProperty(prop.Name);
                            propertyInfo.SetValue(obj, Convert.ChangeType(row[prop.Name], propertyInfo.PropertyType), null);
                        }
                        catch
                        {
                            continue;
                        }
                    }
                    list.Add(obj);
                }
                return list;
            }
            catch
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
```

Note that for example integers are not enclosed in quotes in the final result; there is a type check there, in the extension method. Remember that the names of the properties must correspond to the field names of the DataTable object.

If you do not know the field names and/or do not have a data model at hand, you can use Linq.